# Installing MySQL on CentOS

Tags: mysql, centos, yum

I have set up a nginx server running php-fpm and everything is working great. PHP is compiled with the mysql and mysqli extensions, but I'm having trouble installing MySQL. I did this command:

```
yum install mysql-server mysql-client
```

and it only installed `mysql-server`. it throws this error about `mysql-client`:

```
No package mysql-client available.
```

Now, I think MySQL is installed properly (since it mananged to install mysql-server), but when I type `mysql` in the SSH terminal in order to create databases etc I get this:

```
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

Which leads me to believe I need the `mysql-client` package installed in order to do run commands from the terminal.

Under `/etc/yum.respos.d/` I have:

```
CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  CentOS-Media.repo
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out `yum provides "*/mysql"` to find out which package provides a file in future, but the package is just called mysql in CentOS, so `yum install mysql`.

Comment: I tried `yum install mysql` but it said it was already installed. So I removed `mysql-server` and tried again, and it installed. Now when I run a MySQL command I get this error: `mysql: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
`

Comment: Can you do `rpm -qa | grep mysql` please? Also, which version of CentOS are you running?

Comment: The output of that is:`mysql-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
php-mysql-5.3.3-3.el6_2.5.x86_64
mysql-server-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
mysql-libs-5.1.52-1.el6_0.1.x86_64
`

And I'm running CentOS 6 :)

Comment: Ok it looks like that comes from mysql-libs on CentOS 6.*. It should have been installed as a dependency of mysql I think, but `yum install mysql-libs` should provide you with libmysqlclient.so.16.

Answer (score 3):

The package `mysql-server` is for the server part, `mysql` for the mysql client application and `mysql-libs` for shared libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

"yum install mysql-server mysql"

Or try to download the rpm from the site and install [1]

[1] http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/